# Open page in same browser window from winforms app

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-6

I have a .NET winforms program that includes a feature to launch a specific web page in the system's default browser window.

It would be desirable for the page to be launched in the user's *existing browser window, if one is open*.  The current means of launching the browser always creates a new window:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\path\to\default\browser.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://pageurl";
p.Start();
```

This program is used exclusively on an intranet, and 99% of users are on IE6 (sad, I know.)  Support for other browsers would be nice, but not required.

Any suggestions?  IE6's command line parameters are sparse and do not seem to support this.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but just a random guy piping in: from a usability standpoint, I would HATE that behavior.  Perhaps you have a special circumstance, but an app that hijacks a browser window would piss me off.

Comment: Would it be an option to just embed a browser window inside your app?

Comment: I would not like it either, but it is a popularly requested feature.  I will likely make it a user-controlled setting.

Comment: It would not be an option to use a browser control in this app. Anything but a standard browser window would draw user complaints. Unless I was able to make the control behave exactly like a dedicated window, but I'd consider this a hack and last resort.

Comment: This sounds highly like a WTF in the making then.

Comment: This is simply the tip of the WTF iceberg I'm exposing with this question. The rest of the app, and the purpose for its very existence is more painful, if you'll believe it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have a call center app where like it or not this is required.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The accepted answer is probably the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is that you cannot.

You are spawning a new process that has nothing to do with your application.  You could check to see if a IExplore.EXE process is running, and do some SENDKEYS to the application window, but that is a little sketchy.

You could display the website inside a WebBrowser control, but that is totally different.

Answer (score 1):

What if the user is, well, using that browser page?  You don't want to hijack it.  Modern browsers are smart enough to create a new tab when appropriate.

Comment: "This program is used exclusively on an intranet, and 99% of users are on IE6"

Comment: okay.  Still, you don't want to hijack an active browser window that may be in use.